# Oracle MAF : ListView displaying all data when setEntity sets empty ResultList?

Tags: java, oracle-maf

I am displaying list of data based on the query result in MAF along with A-Team persistence accelerator, below is the sample code which i'm using when some action button has been clicked,

```
ClassMappingDescriptor descriptor = ClassMappingDescriptor.getInstance(PojoClass.class); 
DBPersistenceManager pm= getLocalPersistenceManager();

try {
   StringBuffer sql = pm.getSqlSelectFromPart(descriptor);
   sql.append(" WHERE ACTIVE_FLAG='YES'");    
   sql = pm.constructOrderByClause(sql, descriptor);
   ResultSet set = pm.executeSqlSelect(sql.toString(), new ArrayList());
   List ResultList = pm.createEntitiesFromResultSet(set, (List) descriptor.getAttributeMappingsDirect());
   System.out.println("ResultList size : " +ResultList.size())
   setEntityList(ResultList);
} catch (Exception exp) {
   System.out.println("Exception : " + exp);
}
```

If `ResultList size` returns any value then it is working as expected, But when ever `ResultList size` returns `0` then listView showing all data of the particular associated pojo class table. In this case, actually non of the record should be displayed.

Any help would be appreciated, please comment below if you need any more details regarding this.

Comment: Hi, Can you check the size of ResultList set, set values only if the size is greater than zero

Comment: Yes, I have tried. But for else condition what has to be added, if i ignore it then again it is listing all the data.

Comment: Only add it when the size is greater than zero.. In else no need of anything

Comment: Yeah Anand, I have tried it. In else if i did't set any then it is listing all the data. Since i binding listView in amx screen.

Comment: OK.. Before fetching data just clear the list. Then add. It will work. Don't forget to check the condition